# Can't read characters over 200

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I must read 10 numbers from keyboard and then find the min and max. It works for values between 0-200, but if I type say "232,102,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" the code just says 232 is the lowest and 102 is the biggest.

I

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.data
max db 0
min db 0 
numar db 0
mesaj_min db 13,10, 'Minimul este: $'
mesaj_max db 13,10, 'Maximul este: $'

.code
programStart:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
xor cx,cx
xor bx,bx

mov dl, 10

mov cx, 10
start:

readNumber:
xor ax,ax
mov ah, 01h
int 21h 

cmp al, 13
je incarca_stiva

mov bl, al
sub bl, 30h

mov al, numar
mul dl
add al, bl
mov numar, al

jmp readNumber

incarca_stiva:
xor ax,ax
mov al,numar
push ax
mov numar,0
loop start

val_initiala:
xor ax,ax
pop ax
mov min,al
mov max,al

mov cx,9
comparatie:
pop ax
cmp min,al
jge minim
cmp max,al
jle maxim
jmp repetare

minim:
mov min,al
jmp repetare

maxim:
mov max,al
jmp repetare

repetare:
loop comparatie

xor cx, cx 
xor bx,bx
Descompunere_max:
xor ax, ax
mov al, max
mov dl, 10
div dl 

mov max, al

mov bl, al

add ah, 30h 
mov al, ah
mov ah, 0
push ax 

inc cx

mov al, bl

cmp al, 0 
je AfisareMesaj

jmp Descompunere_max

AfisareMesaj:
mov ah,09H
mov dx, offset mesaj_max
int 21H

AfisareMax:
pop ax 
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, al
int 21h
loop AfisareMax


xor cx, cx 
xor bx,bx
Descompunere_min:
xor ax, ax
mov al, min
mov dl, 10
div dl 

mov min, al

mov bl, al

add ah, 30h 
mov al, ah
mov ah, 0
push ax 

inc cx

mov al, bl

cmp al, 0 
je AfisareMesajMin

jmp Descompunere_min

AfisareMesajMin:
mov ah,09H
mov dx, offset mesaj_min
int 21H

AfisareMin:
pop ax 
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, al
int 21h
loop AfisareMin

SfarsitProgram:
mov ah, 4ch
int 21h


end programStart
```

Results should be:
 "Maximul este: 232"
"Minimul este: 1"

Can someone please explain to me what the problem is?

Comment: You are using signed conditional jump instructions like `jge`.  Use unsigned instructions like `jae` instead.

Comment: Well, that solved it,thank you, but could you please explain what the logic behind it is?

Comment: You are using 8 bit variable for number (8 bit = 1 byte). 8 bits can store 256 combinations of eight 0 or 1 values. The bit pattern `1110_1000`, when interpreted as unsigned 8 bit integer, represents value `232`. But the exact same bit pattern, when interpreted as signed 8 bit integer, represents value `-24`. So you compared it as `-24` (signed 8b integer), but displayed it as `232` (unsigned 8b integer). The byte itself is neither integer, signed, unsigned, nor it does hold any other information, the byte is only eight 0 or 1. So the whole "type" **interpretation** is up to the code using it.

Comment: Thank you very very much